# SQL - How to Query from 3 tables (query in query?)?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, inner-join

I want to know how to complete this query correctly.

I wish to export a full list of votes from all ips used by an user.

---

My database have 3 tables storing the relatives data =>

votes = vote_site_id | vote_ip | vote_time

connexions_ip = adresse_ip | user_id | connexion_time

users = user_id | user_name | user_ip

---

So actually I have this query to have all connexions_ip from one user =>

```
SELECT c.adresse_ip, c.user_id, u.user_name
    FROM connexions_ip c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = '1'
```

And this query to have all votes from one user =>

```
SELECT v.vote_site_id, v.vote_ip, v.vote_time, u.user_name
    FROM votes v 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_ip = v.vote_ip 
WHERE user_id = '1'
```

---

I tried with subquery but I have this error "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
SELECT v.vote_site_id, v.vote_ip, v.vote_time, u.user_name
    FROM votes v 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON (
SELECT c.adresse_ip
    FROM connexions_ip c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = '1'
)
 = v.vote_ip 
WHERE user_id = '1'
```

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try with union ?

Comment: UNION can complete what I want ?
When I try UNION I don't have all votes for différents ip of one user

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: how vote table is related to user ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty vote table is not directly related to user, it store only ip adress, then the table connexions_ip can do the relation between the table users and votes because she contain all ip used by the user

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know sqlfiddle, I will check that to give exemple of my problem.

Comment: hmm thats not correct as per as design is concern, user table can have an ip which not not the same while adding a vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all the table

```
SELECT c.adresse_ip, c.user_id, u.user_name
     , v.vote_site_id, v.vote_ip, v.vote_time
FROM   users u
       LEFT JOIN connexions_ip c ON u.user_id = c.user_id
       LEFT JOIN votes v ON u.user_ip = v.vote_ip 
WHERE  u.user_id = '1'
```

I choosed the table users as the base for `FROM` because is the only table with a condition.

Comment: That's look fine, I'm testing it
But actually I stuck in the fact that's return me too many time the same vote =>
83.157.177.10 1 WolwX 1 83.157.177.10 2014-02-16 14:02:15
37.162.6.178 1 WolwX 1 83.157.177.10 2014-02-16 14:02:15
37.162.234.185 1 WolwX 1 83.157.177.10 2014-02-16 14:02:15
37.160.141.125 1 WolwX 1 83.157.177.10 2014-02-16 14:02:15
37.160.70.55 1 WolwX 1 83.157.177.10 2014-02-16 14:02:15

Comment: I used your query :)

That's ok as far as I tested actually, so thanks @Serpitron

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
select a.*,b.* from (SELECT c.adresse_ip, c.user_id, u.user_name
    FROM connexions_ip c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = '1')a left join (SELECT u.user_id,v.vote_site_id, v.vote_ip, v.vote_time, u.user_name
    FROM votes v 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_ip = v.vote_ip 
WHERE user_id = '1')b on a.user_id  = b.user_id
```